# Drop-shadow is interrupted by invisible borders

Tags: qt, qml

I am making a simple button using the code below

```
Item {
  id: menuButton
  width: 124
  height: 124

  Rectangle {
    id: menuButtonIcon
    x: parent.width - 75
    y: parent.height - 80
    color: "#C02A25"
    width: 60
    height: 60
    radius: width * 0.5
    antialiasing: true
  }

  DropShadow {
        id: menuButtonIconShadow
        source: menuButtonIcon
        anchors.fill: menuButtonIcon
        width: source.width
        height: source.height
        cached: true
        radius: 8.0
        samples: 16
        color: "#000000"
        smooth: true
        horizontalOffset: 10.0
        verticalOffset: 10.0
        spread: 0.2
        transparentBorder: True
    }
}
```

And the resulting shadow looks like it is ending abruptly

[image]

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your `menuButton` is too small.

Comment: My button is fine the way it is. Changing its size will not help because the shadow will follow, and will be cut-off again. But in a smaller button this time.

Comment: This is due to QML scenegraph composing things out of rects by OpenGL, and everything being essentially clipped to its declared dimensions, as I understand it. Was different in QML1. To fix, the shadow item should calculate its proper size (right via bindings on width and height is the simplest way), and use those values.

Comment: ..but given this is a standard item (actually), I'd start with filing a bug (and searching the tracker for alike issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine as long as you write `true` instead of `True`, in the `transparentBorder` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `width` of the item and see if it fixes.

```
id: menuButton
width: 140
height: 140
```

or reduce the size of the `Rectangle` which was given 60X60 dimension. 
Because the position of the button starts at `x=124-75` which is `49` and `y=124-80` which is `44`.

The outer box size is `124` your button starts at `49` and ends `109` (because the `width` is given as `60`). You are left with only `11` pixels for the shadow in the outer box which is not sufficient for the `radius` and `spread` that you are using.

You can also try reducing the spread to `0.15` and `radius` to `6.0` to reduce the shadow

Comment: That is not the reason for the problem. I said that the shadow gets interrupted by invisible borders (or it stops at the imaginary rectangle encompassing its source to be more precise) not by the window or its parent. The issue will persist even if I used an Item of 2000x2000.

Comment: That is an ugly solution though. What if I want a specific spread? There must be some other way I haven't found yet.